# How to know if there is a dependency update available when using Gradle Version Catalog?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

My project is now using a [Version Catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) for all its Gradle modules and now using the type safe declaration of dependencies in its `build.gradle` files. Sadly, I no longer get any suggestions from the IDE when there is an update available for a specific dependency.

What is the best approach to work out whether there is an update available for any of the dependencies instead of checking manually one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) or the [se.ascp.gradle.gradle-versions-filter](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/se.ascp.gradle.gradle-versions-filter) extension of it. Both add an additional gradle task `dependencyUpdates` to your project that will tell you which version updates are available.

It works fine in combination with the new versions catalog feature that you mentioned. I am using it too.

Answer (score 0):

If your `build.gradle` has Maven repositories such as the *Maven Central*, you can also use [MvnCheck](https://github.com/AlexisJehan/MvnCheck). It is a command line tool, which is standalone unlike the *gradle-versions-plugin*. It works for both Maven and Gradle projects.

Output example:

```
2 build file(s) found, checking for artifact updates

my-gradle-project\build.gradle
[COMPILE ONLY] com.google.guava:guava 31.0-android -> 31.1-android
1 artifact update(s) available

my-maven-project\pom.xml
[DEPENDENCY] org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 3.10 -> 3.12.0
[BUILD PLUGIN] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin 3.10.0 -> 3.11.0
2 artifact update(s) available

2/2 build file(s) checked, 3 artifact update(s) available
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of *MvnCheck*.

Comment: I gave it a quick try, but it doesn't seem to work with version catalog.

Comment: Effectively, _Maven Check_ is based on `gradle :dependencies` to retrieve dependencies and their versions, which does not seem to work with the new version catalog feature. It may be fixed with future _Gradle_ releases.